# Cannot pass textarea input to a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea

To begin, I'm working with 3 languages. HTML, Javascript and PHP. I'm unable to pass user inputted textarea text to a PHP variable which would be used as a message in an email that would be sent out. What I believe to be the problem is that my textarea is actually in a modal window and for some reason I think that is what is screwing things up.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<form name="rejectForm" action="">

<div class="rejectModal" title="rejectModal" id="rejectModal" style="display: none; padding:15px ">     

    <b> Text in the modal window</b>
    <center>             
    <textarea id="rejectArea" name="rejectArea" value="{$rejectAreaNote}" rows="6" cols="43"/>    </textarea> 
    </center>
<br/>
<center>

    <input type="button" value="Reject" class="btn success id="submitReject""     id="btnRejectDocumentModal" name="Reject" />    

    <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelSaveModal"  />
</center><br/><br/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function() {  
$(".submitReject").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here  
    $('.error').hide();  
  var rejectAreaNote = $("textarea#rejectArea").val();  
      var noteLength = rejectAreaNote.length;
            if (rejectAreaNote == "" || noteLength < 5) {  
                $("label#rejectArea_error").show();  
                $("textarea#rejectArea").focus();  
    return false;  
}  
var dataString = rejectAreaNote;  
alert (dataString);return false;  
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "gs_ViewDocument.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {  
        $('#reject_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
        $('#message').html("Reject Form Submitted!");
        }  
    });  
    return false;  
   });  
 });
```

What creates the Modal (JS):

```
    $('.rejectModal').css("background", "lightblue");
        $('#btnRejectDocument').bind(isTouchScreen ? "touchstart" : "click", function(){
       if (!gsSelection.unselectElem()) return false; 
           $('.rejectModal').dialog({
           modal:true, 
           resizable:false,
       width: 400,
   }).removeClass("ui-widget-content");
   $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
   return;
});
$('#btnRejectDocumentModal').bind(isTouchScreen ? "touchstart" : "click", function(){
   $(this).parents('div.rejectModal').dialog('close');
});
$('#btnCancelSaveModal').bind(isTouchScreen ? "touchstart" : "click", function(){
   $(this).parents('div.rejectModal').dialog('close');
});
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Reject'])&&$_POST['Reject']=='Reject') 
{
    $isReject = true;
    RejectAction($DocumentID, $ClientName, $ClientEmail);
    $smartyvalues["isReject"] = $isReject;
    $smartyvalues["RejectMsg"] = "The document invitation was successfully rejected!";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? Have you tried console logging the form after you submit it to make sure the data is even making it to a server request?

Comment: Bad indenting, I'm lazy to fix, skip question...

Answer (score 1):

Try the below is should fix it :

```
 <textarea id="rejectArea" name="rejectArea"  rows="6" cols="43"> {$rejectAreaNote}</textarea>
```

you were closing your `textarea` tag twice `/>` and then `</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Reject" class="btn success id="submitReject""     id="btnRejectDocumentModal" name="Reject" />
```

The closing quotes here are wrong (Two quotes after submitReject).